# Change value of hidden form field to range of entered number

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

i have a simple text input field users put in a number. I need to check which range the number matches (e.g. >10 or <1 ) and save a separate key/value for that range in the database.

I thought about a hidden field that changes its value as the user enters data but i don't know how to determine the range.

*(I cannot modify the submit button. I use php and jQuery.)*

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ranges are fixed and you are asking about client side code then

```
var ranges = {'range1':{min:-1000,max:2},'range2':{min:3,max:10},'range3':{min:11,max:1000}};

$('#number').keyup(findRange);

function findRange(){
    var num = parseInt( $('#number').val() );
    $('#secret').val('');
    for(rng in ranges)
    {
        if (num >= ranges[rng].min && num <=ranges[rng].max)
        {
            $('#secret').val(rng);
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: http://www.jsfiddle.net/hbPj9/

Answer (score 1):

Relatively simple...

```
$num = (int) $_POST['num'];
if ($num < 1) {
    // do something
}
elseif ($num > 10) {
    // do something else
}
```